# vertical scroll on parts of pivot page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, listbox, pivot

I have a problem scrolling vertically within a data bound pivot page (WP 7.1).

I have tried the different solutions posted here and on MSDN, but none of them seem to work for me..
I have a list
 of News objects in an ObservableCollection that I am displaying in a pivot page. So far so good...

I want to be able to scroll the main text of the news item, but have the menu and headline stationary on the page.
I have tried making a grid and surrounding the scrollable content by a Listbox and now a ScrollViewer, but I am not able to scroll on the page.. When I try scrolling, I can scroll a couple of lines of text, and then the text reverts to the original position. Very frustrating!!!

The code I have tried is this:

```
    <!--Pivot Control-->
    <controls:Pivot  x:Name="PivotNews"  
                     Grid.Row="2"
        ItemsSource="{Binding NewsCollection}" >
        <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!--<TextBlock Text="Seneste nyheder" />-->
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <!--<RowDefinition Height="*" />-->
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid x:Name="HeaderLine"
                              Grid.Row ="0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}" 
                                Grid.Column="0" 
                                   Height="150"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" 
                               FontWeight="ExtraBold" 
                               FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               Grid.Column="1" 
                               Margin="10,0,0,10"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewerNews" Grid.Row="1">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SubHeader}" 
                                   FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}" 
                                   FontWeight="Bold" 
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MainText}" 
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove first StackPanel in your ItemTemplate.

When you use StackPanel, it has it's own height, that does not depend on Page height, and row height value "*" tries to fit in the available space, that is in this case bigger, than the pages height.

Comment: Perfect!!

Thank you very much :-)

So the thing i entered to provide the scroll screewed it up instead... The learning curve is steep ;-)